# Bank's Reporting Responsibilities on Closing Accounts

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, credit-report

Is a bank required under law to report the bank's closing of your account to ChexSystems or any credit reporting agency

Comment: Depends on the reason they closed it. If it was simply that it went to zero and they culled it, generally no. But if say you were negative or overdrawn for an extended period, or for some other adverse reason, then almost certainly yes. Just like any other credit agency, they are regulated to disclose,so if you are concerned, request a report from them to see what is on there about you.

Comment: Please add a country tag.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is No. Reporting to any of the credit reporting agencies is entirely at the discretion of the entity doing the reporting (the furnisher). None of it is "required" by law to *be* reported. The law (FCRA) only requires that the information reported cannot "knowingly" be inaccurate.